# WFS GetFeature with propertyName get response without geometry

Tags: geoserver, geometry, wfs, getfeature, propertyname

I have a WFS request send to a GeoServer:

http://localhost:8600/geoserver/aa/ows?service=WFS &version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=aa:bb&outputFormat=json&propertyName=attr1,attr2

I cannot get all features with only attr1 and attr2 value. When requesting every feature's geometry the response is `null`.

When I send a similar request without `propertyName` parameter, the geometry is back.

I want to have both the `geometry` and `attr1`, `attr2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In WFS geometry is also just a property. If you do not use PropertyName parameter then all the parameters are included but if you use PropertyName then you must include into the request all the (non-mandatory) parameters that you want .

Compare

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&TypeNames=states&count=2&PropertyName=STATE_NAME&outputformat=application/json

and

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&TypeNames=states&count=2&PropertyName=STATE_NAME,the_geom&outputformat=application/json

The name of the geometry property is checked with the DescribeFeatureType request

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&TypeName=states

You can see below that for this feature type the name of the geometry property is "the_geom". You can also see that all properties are nillable=true and minOccurs="0" so they are not included in the result set if they are not requested. If some properties in a WFS service are not-nillable or if they have minOccurs greater than zero then they are mandatory and always included in the result even if not requested with PropertyName.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsd:schema xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.openplans.org/topp">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="http://demo.geo-solutions.it:80/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="statesType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="the_geom" nillable="true" type="gml:MultiSurfacePropertyType"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="STATE_NAME" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="STATE_FIPS" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SUB_REGION" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="STATE_ABBR" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="LAND_KM" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="WATER_KM" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PERSONS" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="FAMILIES" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="HOUSHOLD" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="MALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="FEMALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="WORKERS" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="DRVALONE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CARPOOL" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PUBTRANS" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="EMPLOYED" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="UNEMPLOY" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SERVICE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="MANUAL" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="P_MALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="P_FEMALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SAMP_POP" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="states" substitutionGroup="gml:AbstractFeature" type="topp:statesType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what I need.

Comment: One more question. It is possible to set the the_geom' attribution nillable=false? Because I saw someone don't request attribution like the_geom, still get gemetry. Or why my the_geom is nillable=true?

Comment: It is set in that way be default with GeoServers. Please explain "Because I saw someone don't request attribution like the_geom, still get gemetry.". Where did you see that? In the logs of your server? Somewhere in the internet? GeoServer is possible to configure to show nillable=false but it is a bit complicated. Manual is here https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/schemamapping.html.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes I saw in the internet. I will check the link you mentioned.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I request `PropertyName=au:name` but this WFS service still returns geometry:  https://www.ign.es/wfs-inspire/unidades-administrativas?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=au:AdministrativeUnit&FILTER=%3CFilter%3E%3CBBOX%3E%3CValueReference%3Ead:position/ad:GeographicPosition/ad:geometry%3C/ValueReference%3E%3Cgml:Envelope%20xmlns:gml=%22http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2%22%3E%3Cgml:lowerCorner%3E42.9679%20-9.2538%3C/gml:lowerCorner%3E%3Cgml:upperCorner%3E42.9579%20-9.2438%3C/gml:upperCorner%3E%3C/gml:Envelope%3E%3C/BBOX%3E%3C/Filter%3E&PropertyName=au:name

Comment: That could mean that geometry is not nillable in the XML schema but I am not good at reading the INSPIRE schemas. Links that you can follow are https://www.ign.es/wfs-inspire/unidades-administrativas?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&TYPENAME=au:AdministrativeUnit which points to https://www.ign.es/wfs-inspire/appschemas/GeographicalNames.xsd and https://www.ign.es/wfs-inspire/appschemas/GeographicalNames.xsd. But WFS with complex content (application schema) like INSPIRE datasets tends to be problematic.